# Structure sheaf of the projectivization of a bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $0\to V'\to V\to M \to 0$ be an exact sequence with $V$ a vector bundle over a scheme $B$, $M \in \operatorname{Pic}(B) $. Let $H:=\mathbb{P}(V')$ be the Cartier divisor, let $p: \mathbb{P}(V) \to B$ be the projection. Let $X:=\mathbb{P}(V)$ Why is

> $\mathcal O_{X}(H) = \mathcal O_{X}(1) \otimes p^{*} M $?

Any reference is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tautological embedding
$$
\mathcal{O}_X(-1) \hookrightarrow p^*V
$$
and an exact sequence $0 \to p^*V' \to p^*V \to p^*M \to 0$.
It is clear that $H$ is the zero locus of the composition
$$
\mathcal{O}_X(-1) \to p^*V \to p^*M,
$$
which is nothing but the zero locus of the corresponding section of the line bundle
$$
\mathcal{O}_X(-1)^\vee \otimes p^*M \cong
\mathcal{O}_X(1) \otimes p^*M.
$$
This means that $\mathcal{O}_X(H) \cong \mathcal{O}_X(1) \otimes p^*M$.

Comment: Could you please explain why  $H=\mathbb{P}(V')$ is the zero locus of  $\mathcal{O}_X(-1) \to p^*M$? And if $H$ is the zero locus of $s: \mathcal O_X \to \mathcal O_X(1)\otimes p^*M $, why is $\mathcal O_X(H) = \{f\in K(X): (f)+H\ge 0\} = \mathcal O_X(1)\otimes p^*M$ ? I couldn't see the connection between the two? (Here I mean by $K(X)$ the function field of X)